# Password Complexity Inconsistent in IE11 And Chrome

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have created one b2c password reset policy and I have set complexity Like below

[image]

***But in IE11 it's showing wrong Message Like this:***

[image]

***Chrome shows like below:***

[image]

Comment: Does it actually accept passwords with only 3? Or does it force you to use all 4? What have you tried? What have you tested, and what were the results? Please provide additional (relevant) information.

Comment: it's accepting password with 3, and I found sometimes it's working as expected example it's showing  "The password must have at least 4 of the following:"

Comment: @Manish Tiwari Don't be worry about the issue. If is it happened on your side but it would not remain longer. You could try after some time. Thank you and happy coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your problem. But It seems alright now. It might occurs as everyday azure's features improving. So I believe it won't be a big concern.  See my flow...

**Official Document:**

[image]

**Password Reset Flow Settings:**

[image]

**IE 11 and Edge**

[image]

**Chrome Version 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)**

[image]

> **Note:** Talk to our internal technical team as they said it might happened due to some incremental task or enhancement something like But exact
> reason is anonymous.

[image]

***You could also send your feedback on mentioned address [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory). For further product improvement.***

Comment: @Manish Tiwari If my answer was helpful you could it answer to help other. Thank you.